# How to delete part of cache in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I need to save space in thunderbird. I don't want to delete messages on server but only the local copy (I have tight quota).

How to do this (I tried compacting folders and I cannot see the option of deleting cache - even unticking the synchronisation doesn't do this).

Comment: The large cache in TB appears to be the directory cache2. It contains over 500 MB. I'm afraid of deleting it.